# How to detect press gesture on Column (Jetpack Compose)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to detect a press gesture on a `Column` in Jetpack Compose.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onPress = {
                    Log.d("OnPress", "I've been pressed")
                },
                onTap =  {
                    Log.d("OnPress", "I've been tapped")
                },
                onDoubleTap = {
                    Log.d("OnPress", "Got double tapped")
                },
                onLongPress = {
                    Log.d("OnPress", "Long pressed")
                }
            )
        }
)
```

However, none of the logs are working.

I've seen `InteractionSource` having a way to collect information about whether a component is pressed/focused etc. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/handling-interaction#interaction-state

But I can't give my `Column` an interaction source as a parameter.

So how do I get press detected on my `Column`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both Modifiers, **`clickable`** and **`pointerInput`** are set on the same Composable, the **later one** in the `Modifier` chain will be used.

```
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            //
        }
        .clickable { Log.d("OnClick", "Click") }
```

If `clickable()` comes after `pointerInput`, all of gesture `onPress`, `onTap`,`onDoubleTap` and `onLongPress` will be ignored and `clickable()` will be invoked instead.

As result:

```
D/OnClick: Click
```

Instead:

```
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable { Log.d("OnClick", "Click") }
        .pointerInput(Unit){
            //your code
        }
```

as result:

```
E/OnPress: I've been pressed
E/OnPress: I've been tapped
```

You can also use the [**`Modifier.combinedClickable()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).combinedClickable(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0)) to listen for single, double, and long clicks.

```
   Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .combinedClickable(
                onLongClick =  { Log.d("OnClick", "Long click") },
                onDoubleClick = { Log.d("OnClick", "Double click")},
                onClick = {  Log.d("OnClick", "Click")}
            )
   )
```